# Load content via AJAX in jQuery (CodeIgniter view)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I found a nice example on how to use AJAX in jQuery at this link: 
http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/how-to-load-content-via-ajax-in-jquery/

I added contents from `index.html` file to my `view.php` file (I'm using CodeIgniter).

Everything looks okay, but when you want to switch to another section, page content doesn't change (same content as before shows up).

I think maybe there is a problem, for `menu.js` file to pass data to CodeIgniter `view.php` file?

Could you give me any suggestions on how could I solve this problem? I hope this would be helpful for others too.

Menu.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//References
var sections = $("#menu li");
var loading = $("#loading");
var content = $("#content");

//Manage click events
sections.click(function(){
    //show the loading bar
    showLoading();
    //load selected section
    switch(this.id){
        case "home":
            content.slideUp();
            content.load("sections.html #section_home", hideLoading);
            content.slideDown();
            break;
        case "news":
            content.slideUp();
            content.load("sections.html #section_news", hideLoading);
            content.slideDown();
            break;
        case "interviews":
            content.slideUp();
            content.load("sections.html #section_interviews", hideLoading);
            content.slideDown();
            break;
        case "external":
            content.slideUp();
            content.load("external.html", hideLoading);
            content.slideDown();
            break;
        default:
            //hide loading bar if there is no selected section
            hideLoading();
            break;
    }
});

//show loading bar
function showLoading(){
    loading
        .css({visibility:"visible"})
        .css({opacity:"1"})
        .css({display:"block"})
    ;
}
//hide loading bar
function hideLoading(){
    loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);
};
```

});

Animations from javascript is working (loading/content/sections) , but the real content isn't loaded from html file.

As I said it looks like this script can't load content to the view.php file (which is CodeIgniter 'view' file)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: wheres the javascript? the php?

Comment: All the files you can find in that link. 
On my configuration:
Javascript file is in /scripts folder in apache server www directory, and view.php file is in /application/view/lab/view.php folder.

Comment: @jomajo - RPM is asking for *your* code, not the library code or example code. How do you expect someone to solve your problem when we don't have your code?  Do you ask your mechanic to fix your car by locking it in your garage and hiding the keys and then just referring him to the technical manual?  Probably not an apples to apples comparison, but I hope it makes sense to you that if you want people to answer your question you have to show them the code you're using. :)

Comment: Hi , code added. As I said, the code isn't modified, I just want to know, why that script can't pass the data to the VIEW, and how we can fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter needs to serve `sections.html` and `external.html`. It will not do so by default.

Assuming `view.php` is used for the URL `http://example.com/index.php/mycontroller/view`, then jQuery will send requests for the following URLs.

```
http://example.com/index.php/mycontroller/sections.html
http://example.com/index.php/mycontroller/external.html
```

Unless you have told CodeIgniter what to do for these requests, CodeIgniter will return a 404 and your page content will not be updated.

Comment: But if I add tihs row, in javascript: `content.load("<?=base_url()?>sections.html #section_home", hideLoading);` Nothings change. There is no 404 error. The content in other sections is the same as in the first section. 

Also if I add function `section` to my controller, with echo statement, slide just goes up, and also nothings happens.

Comment: Awesome, I solved the problem:D

Just added this to my controller:

     `function sections()
               {
                $this->load->view('view/sections.html');
               }    `